# shell script to call ls command every time i change directories

Tags: linux, shell, ls, cd

I am wondering if there is any way to make a script, that would run in the background and which will call the "ls" command every time I change directories("cd") in Linux.

I know that in order to put a process in the background you add a "&" when you run it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could replace `cd` with a shell function in your `~/.bashrc` or similar startup script:

```
function cd {
    builtin cd "$@"
    RET=$?
    ls
    return $RET
}
```

this would also return the exit code of `cd`, just in case...

`builtin` is a shell builtin to execute the shell builtin `cd` instead of the `cd` funciton, to avoid running into a recursive loop - at least in bash - but should also work with other shells...

Comment: thanks, it works perfectly, but only if I put the code ~/.bashrc

Comment: yes, you're right, this won't work in `~/.profile` because that is only soucred at login. removed it.

Comment: vote up: Exactly what I was looking for!  Learned something new about `builtin` function and I wish I knew about this as I think it is very valuable item under your belt while programming a script.  Thank you!

Comment: what's the diff between `builtin cd "$@"` and `command cd "$@"`?

Comment: @AlexanderMills both bypass shell functions with the same name, `builtin` explicitly calls a shell builtin, `command` also considers executables on the path. See the [manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bash-Builtins) for a more detailled explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can define a function in your `.bashrc` like this to achieve that:

```
cdlist(){
        cd "$1" && ls
}
```

Comment: And then, you can `alias cd=cdlist`.

Comment: Rather than creating a function and then using an alias, you can simply name the function `cd` and avoid recursion by doing: `cd() { command cd "$@" && ls; }`